# Getting RGB from Tango in the new Unity api

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

There seems to be alot of answers to this for the older version of the Tango Unity API, but with Leibniz it seems to have changed. I want to get the RGB info for the back facing non fish eye lens camera.

```
public void OnTangoImageAvailableEventHandler(Tango.TangoEnums.TangoCameraId cameraId,Tango.TangoUnityImageData imageBuffer)
```

I am using this method inside a class inherited from ITangoVideoOverlay. but the image buffer returns a byte[] in HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YV12, and I just don't know how to deal with it, without any example code.

Answer (score 0):

The [AugmentedRealityUnity Example](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/tree/master/ExperimentalProjects) on Github (they updated it 10 days ago) has a YUVShader that may do what you need. I'm trying to use that with the PointCloud example to see if I can colorize the pointcloud with rgb data. Don't have it working yet.

Comment: If you manage to get it to work I would love to get a hint as to how, because it seems to be hard to get access to it.